# Images are not loaded in visual-studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I run my web site with visual-studio 2015 , my image address is http://template/desktop/.../test.png and my images are not displaied. my address should be http://localhost:2323/template/desktop/.../test.png

why localhost:2323 is not put in my address when I run my web site in vs2015

Comment: What is the rendered HTML markup of your `<img />` elements?

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET WebForms or ASP.NET MVC project? If it's MVC are you using ASPX or Razor? Are you using .NET Core or the full-fat .NET Framework?

Comment: yes it is <img src="//template/desktop/.../test.png" width="785" height="95" />

Comment: I'm using .net faramework 4.6 . and it is ASP.NET WebForms. It is not MVC